# d3.js csv loading - simple data conversion

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am loading a csv file by using `d3.csv`function

```
d3.csv(files[0],
    function (d) {

        return {
            col1: +d["col1"],
            col2: +d["col2"],
            col3: +d["col3"]            
        };           
    },
function(error, data) {...});
```

where I use `function(d)` to convert all the data to numerics. Is there a way to simplify the code and process all the columns without explicitly  referring to their names?

Comment: Hey can you explain a bit in what do you actually want to achieve and the data format thatyou are getting in the variable d.

Comment: I am loading a csv file, all numbers. To be recognized as numbers, I need to run those += conversion statements, it works fine, but I would like to do it in a way I don't explicitly mention the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do the same thing repeatedly. This calls for a loop (e.g. a for-loop or a map).

```
function (d) {
  var result = {};
  for (key in d) {
    result[key] = +d[key];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Great! One more question: can I put this code inside my third argument (`function(error, data)`)?

Comment: In general you can do whatever you like within the callback functions, because that's simply plain javascript. So yes, you can do that. However  conversions are usually done in the accessor function.